# HTML Video For Mobile, Tablet, Desktop

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic video tag that I am using as a banner on a page:

```
<video playsinline="" autoplay="" muted="" loop="" preload="auto">
      <source src="/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="/example.webm" type="video/webm">
      Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
    </video>
```

This video, with a higher resolution takes up around 12mb, it is the same video on mobile, tablet and desktop.

I have been using a library for images called lazysizes (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) which works perfectly for using different images based on the width of where it is viewed which helps save significant bandwidth:

```
<img
    data-sizes="auto"
    data-src="image2.jpg"
    data-srcset="image1.jpg 300w,
    image2.jpg 600w,
    image3.jpg 900w" class="lazyload" />
```

Is their an equivalent method for video tags using JS/HTML? I could write this in PHP, using the mobile detect library (http://mobiledetect.net/) and say if mobile or tablet, show this lower resolution video. I am just wondering if there is an approach like lazysizes for videos.